# is there any way query LC_CTYPE locale character class expressions?

Tags: posix, locale

https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03_05
**9.3.5 RE Bracket Expression** section 6 quote:

> The following character class expressions shall be supported in all
> locales:
>
> [:alnum:]   [:cntrl:]   [:lower:]   [:space:] [:alpha:]   [:digit:]
> [:print:]   [:upper:] [:blank:]   [:graph:]   [:punct:]   [:xdigit:]
>
> In addition, character class expressions of the form:
>
> [:name:]
>
> are recognized in those locales where the name keyword has been given
> a charclass definition in the LC_CTYPE category

`echo $LC_ALL`
return
`en_US.utf8`

after reading this: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap07.html#tag_09_03_05
I seems get it. Different locale have different character class expressions. The above mentioned apply to all locale.

I wonder, Is there any way to query the current locale LC_CTYPE attribute (character class expressions)?

For one, In en_US.utf8, [:name:] can be [:word:] as far as i know.

Comment: On GNU systems at least, try `locale ctype-class-names`